# Java subclass vs superclass inherited variables clarification

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, super, instance-variables

**ABOUT ME**:
I am learning Java because I want to become a software developer someday and I came across the topic of subclasses and their ability to inherit from superclasses on tutorialspoint.com.

**where I may need correction**

1. So let's say I made a class with an instance variable declared as int age; It also has a method for printing its age.

```java
class Superclass {
    int age = 3;

    public void printAge() {
        System.out.println(age);
    }
}
```

2. Then I make a subclass that extends to the initial class. The subclass would inherit the instance variable, correct?

```java
class Subclass extends Superclass {
    //invisible instance variable int age = 3;

}
```

3. So, if I used the printAge() method on a subclass object, it should print out a 3, right?

```java
Subclass obj = new Subclass();
obj.printAge(); --> 3
```

4. So far, using the (.printAge) method that was inherited, I could access the super instance variable (age) without the super keyword. But, if I were to set up an instance variable for the subclass from the beginning, I would *have* to use the super keyword to get the same output as before, right?

```java
class Subclass extends Superclass {
    //invisible instance variable int age = 3;
    int age;

}

Subclass obj = new Subclass();
obj.printAge(); --> null
```

5. Let me override the print function for the subclass to make what I mean a little more clear.

```java
class Subclass extends Superclass {
    //invisible instance variable int age = 3;
    int age;

    public void printAge() {
        System.out.println(super.age); -- > 3
        System.out.println(age); -- > null
    }
}
```

6. I am pretty sure that before I made an instance variable explicitly for the subclass, I could reference the super inherited age variable using (age). But only after I made the instance variable explicitly would I *have* to use the super keyword to differentiate the super and sub instance variables. Does this mean that the inherited super variables will take the spot of an instance variable until the programmer explicitly assigned one for the subclass, in which case only THEN would you *have* to use the super keyword? Am I correct in this assumption?

I tried to find out why is it that I didn't need to use the super keyword to access an inherited instance variable until I explicitly made one in the subclass.

Assuming I am correct, I wasn't aware that a subclass would LITERALLY inherit a super variable, and would also allow you to make an instance variable of the same name in that super class, meaning that you can utilize two variables at all times. Maybe I am dumb, but it didn't click in my head until now, assuming I am correct in thinking this.

**EXTRA:**
I would appreciate any advice on the steps to becoming a great software developer. For example, "Where should I go from here after learning Java", or "How can I apply the Java code to make software?" to be more specific. Some advice for internships or preparations for internships would be welcome as well.

Comment: BTW an `int` variable/field will never be `null` - primitives (`int`, `byte`, `char`, `float`, ...) cannot be `null`, only reference types (`String`, `Object`, `Integer`, ...) can be `null` -- `println(age)` with `int age` will never print `null`

Comment: You stumbled over [field hiding (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). In essence: both super- and subclass have a field `int age` when we declare the field in both classes. They are separate and can have distinct values. This is generally seen as a code smell and should be avoided. The field `int age` in `Subclass` should be removed.

Comment: "*I would appreciate any advice on the steps to becoming a great software developer.*" - Ask 10 people, get 11 answer. This is primarily opinion-based and therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Regarding "extra": please check out the [ask] and [tour] links to see why this is far off-topic. The site is for questions and answers of specific code problems, and isn't for career or academic advice. Best to ask such questions on a discussion forum, which isn't what this site is not a forum. Reddit or Quora might be better for these types of questions.